# How do I prevent invalid values in an AnyVal derivative

Tags: scala, assert, primitive

In an attempt to remain strongly typed, prevent invalid states, and maintain the efficiencies of a JVM primitive type, I am attempting to do the following which is returning a compilation error of "this statement is not allowed in value class - assert(!((double < -180.0d) || ...".

```
case class Longitude(double: Double) extends AnyVal {
  assert(!((double < -180.0d) || (double > 180.0d)), s"double [$double] must not be less than -180.d or greater than 180.0d")

  def from(double: Double): Option[Longitude] =
    if ((double < -180.0d) || (double > 180.0d))
      None
    else
      Some(Longitude(double))
}
```

My desired effect is to prevent invalid instances from existing, like Longitude(-200.0d). What options do I have for achieving the desired effect?

Comment: This project can be interesting https://github.com/fwbrasil/bond

Comment: Value class is designed to be simple values with extension methods only. Anything more will require an actual class (allocated on the heap) due to JVM limitations, so it doesn't support constructor. Other options like Refined looks good but it will actually create instances on the heap too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an amazing library [Refined](https://github.com/fthomas/refined) which aimed to solved exactly this sort of problems: prove on type level certain validation. Also this approach know in community as "Making illegal states unrepresentable".  More then then - it provides compilation level checks along with runtime validations.

In your case possible solution might look like:

```
import eu.timepit.refined._
import eu.timepit.refined.api.Refined
import eu.timepit.refined.auto._
import eu.timepit.refined.numeric._
import eu.timepit.refined.boolean._

type LongtitudeValidation = Greater[W.`180.0`.T] Or Less[W.`-180.0`.T]

/**
* Type alise for double which should match condition `((double < -180.0d) || (double > 180.0d))` at type level
*/
type Longtitude = Double Refined LongtitudeValidation

val validLongTitude: Longtitude = refineMV(190.0d))

val invalidLongTitude: Longtitude = refineMV(160.0d)) //this won't compile because of validation failures
//error you will see: Both predicates of ((160.0 > 180.0) || (160.0 < -180.0)) failed. Left: Predicate failed: (160.0 > 180.0). Right: Predicate failed: (160.0 < -180.0).
```

Also you can use runtime verification via `refineV` method:

```
type LongtitudeValidation = Greater[W.`180.0`.T] Or Less[W.`-180.0`.T]
type Longtitude = Double Refined LongtitudeValidation

val validatedLongitude1: Either[String, Longtitude] = refineV(190.0d)
println(validatedLongitude1)

val validatedLongitude2: Either[String, Longtitude] = refineV(160.0d)
println(validatedLongitude2)
```

which will print out:

```
Right(190.0)
Left(Both predicates of ((160.0 > 180.0) || (160.0 < -180.0)) failed. Left: Predicate failed: (160.0 > 180.0). Right: Predicate failed: (160.0 < -180.0).)
```

You can play and check by yourself in Scatie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/CQktleObQlKWKYby0vaszA

UPD:

Thanks to @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez who suggested to use refined with [scala-newtype](https://github.com/estatico/scala-newtype) to avoid additional memory allocations.

Comment: You need to combine **refined** with [**scala-newtype**](https://github.com/estatico/scala-newtype) to get the desired effect of no allocation.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez good to know, thank you fir telling. Will update answer.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Perhaps i'm doing something wrong but newtype not so easy to make work with refined: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ZzYBxeOAScygL4jHqiQKuQ

Comment: I didn't say it was easy :sweat_smile: those two are very advanced libraries which exploit very advanced features of the language. I only said that was the way to accomplish that :) - Check [this](https://blog.softwaremill.com/a-simple-trick-to-improve-type-safety-of-your-scala-code-ba80559ca092) - BTW, you have the refined wrong, it should be greater than `-180` **AND** less than `180`.

Comment: I don't follow `Right(190)` as 190 is clearly outside the valid range of -180 to 180.

Comment: Your "Type alise for double..." comment is asserting the precondition incorrectly. There is a NOT (!) at the start of the precondition. The only valid values are exactly inclusively -180.0 to exactly 180.0. And I don't want `equals` performed at the bounds of the range, only greater than, less than, because of unreliable effects of `equal` for a `Double`. Hence, the preceding NOT (!).

Comment: I went to the Scastie link and tried to edit the logic to turn it into the inclusive range (specified in my prior comment). However wasn't able to figure that out. I will try to come back later and read through the Refined docs to see if I can figure out the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using the following approach:

```
  case class Longitude private (double: Double) extends AnyVal
  object Longitude {
     def apply(double: Double): Longitude = {
      if((double < -180.0d) || (double > 180.0d)) throw new RuntimeException(s"double [$double] must not be less than -180.d or greater than 180.0d")
      else new Longitude(double)
    }
  }
  Longitude(179)
  Longitude(190) // java.lang.RuntimeException: double [190.0] must not be less than -180.d or greater than 180.0d
```

Also, you can use `Either`, `Option` as @Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez & @Ivan Kurchenko mentioned bellow

`Either` Example:

```
  def DoSomething = println("Exception happened")
  def DoSomethingElse = println("Instance created")
  case class Longitude private(double: Double) extends AnyVal

  object Longitude {
    def apply(double: Double): Either[String, Longitude] = {
      if ((double < -180.0d) || (double > 180.0d)) Left(s"double [$double] must not be less than -180.d or greater than 180.0d")
      else Right(new Longitude(double))
    }
  }

  Longitude(181).fold(
    ex => DoSomething,
    longitude => DoSomethingElse
  )
```

Or merge it both together:

```
  case class Longitude private (double: Double) extends AnyVal
  object Longitude {
    def apply(double: Double): Longitude =
      safeCreate(double).getOrElse(throw new IllegalArgumentException((s"double [$double] must not be less than -180.d or greater than 180.0d")))

    private def safeCreate(double: Double) =
      if (!((double < -180.0d) || (double > 180.0d))) Some(new Longitude(double))
      else None
  }
  Longitude(170)
  Longitude(181) // java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: double [181.0] must not be less than -180.d or greater than 180.0d
```

But probably better solution is to use @Ivan answer

Comment: Mostly the idea of making invalid states unrepresentable is also tied to the idea of not having runtime errors. Also I can just `Longitude(179).copy(-1000)` and broken program.

Comment: Throwing exceptions, especially for validation considered, as bad practice, because it makes function impure  and Scala compiler does not force to handle it. Using Either, cats validated considered as better options.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the solution using `Either`

Answer (score 1):

While I *really* like the [Refined answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65921340/501113), for my needs it both introduces a new library and it produces too much boilerplate for this particular tiny use case. An unspecified requirement is that I'll be showing it to Scala newbs, and this solution is way too advanced for them.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65921598/501113) gave me the basic pattern at which I was trying to discover. However, it wasn't quite there, either.

Below is what I ended up choosing to do. You can view and play with the code at [this Scastie link](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/b1fT4RFJRZKiJTwlUeOmkw):

```
object Longitude extends (Double => Longitude) {
  def apply(double: Double): Longitude =
    applyFp(double) match {
      case Right(longitude) => longitude
      case Left(errorDetails) => throw new IllegalArgumentException(errorDetails)
    }

  def applyFp(double: Double): Either[String, Longitude] =
    if (!((double < -180.0d) || (double > 180.0d)))
      Right(new Longitude(double))
    else
      Left(s"double [$double] must not be less than -180.d or greater than 180.0d")
}
final case class Longitude private (double: Double) extends AnyVal


//Tests
Longitude.applyFp(179.0d)
Longitude.applyFp(180.0d)
Longitude.applyFp(190.0d) //returns Either.Left

Longitude(179.0d)
Longitude(180.0d)
//Remove comment from next line which will then throw the exception "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: double [190.0] must not be less than -180.d or greater than 180.0d"
//Longitude(190.0d)
```

Thank you to those who provided insightful answers. It was a very valuable learning experience.

For those who understand more of the internal details of how case classes work, specifically around the compiler automatically providing a `copy` method, here's the code updated to accommodate that "security hole" with it available at [this Scastie link](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/oNmCv2m6QgGN4DZSXJ0uzg):

```
object Longitude extends (Double => Longitude) {
  def apply(double: Double): Longitude =
    applyFp(double) match {
      case Right(longitude) => longitude
      case Left(errorDetails) => throw new IllegalArgumentException(errorDetails)
    }

  def applyFp(double: Double): Either[String, Longitude] =
    if (!((double < -180.0d) || (double > 180.0d)))
      Right(new Longitude(double))
    else
      Left(s"double [$double] must not be less than -180.d or greater than 180.0d")
}
final case class Longitude private (double: Double) extends AnyVal {
  def copy(double: Double = double): Longitude =
    Longitude.apply(double)
}


//Tests
Longitude.applyFp(179.0d)
Longitude.applyFp(180.0d)
Longitude.applyFp(190.0d) //returns Either.Left

Longitude(179.0d)
Longitude(180.0d)
//Remove comment from next line which will then throw the exception "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: double [190.0] must not be less than -180.d or greater than 180.0d"
//Longitude(190.0d)

val longitude = Longitude(-170.0d)
//Remove comment from next line which will then throw the exception "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: double [-200.0] must not be less than -180.d or greater than 180.0d"
//longitude.copy(-200.0d)
```

Comment: NP, im glad its helped. anyways, you creating new Longitude twice, once on the `applyFp` and once on the `apply`.
You can change the `apply` match to: `applyFp(double).fold( errorDetails => throw new IllegalArgumentException(errorDetails), obj => obj)` or use last edit of my previous comment (also match with just passing the obj)

Comment: Note that this can be broken using `copy`. The best is to use a normal `final class Longitude` and define all that you need. Second, note that **Value classes** can produce worse performance than regular classes, since they are actually not guaranteed to do not box and in turn can box and unbox multiple times, in general, they are considered a failed experiment for modeling, they are useful for extension methods or partially applied tricks.

Comment: @ZviMints Tysvm for your feedback. I have fixed the code and the Scastie. And I like how you handled it with `.getOrElse`, too. So many different options.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Tysvm for the `final` adjustment. Tysvm for also calling out the issue with `copy` being broken. Serializations's `readResolve` is also broken (`private def readResolve(): Object = ???`). I will extend my answer to satisfy those a bit later. Agreed about boxing/unboxing. I'll mildly disagree with "failed experiment". My experience has been anything but failure in this particular area.

Comment: I'm incorrect. It appears that `readResolve()` is not implemented on classes extending `AnyValue`. I have added an additional solution which just adds the `copy` method. It does mean, though, that there is a Serialization hole that appears unable to be closeable.

Comment: @chaotic3quilibrium Why exactly do you think it is not a failed experiment? - In any case, Java's serialization is another failed experiment, you should not really depend on that for anything important.